# How can I fix cannot open display?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vncviewer

I am new to climate modeling, cdo and ubuntu. I have downloaded every possible thing for working with cdo in ubuntu, but whenever I want to have a graphical look into my data I cannot display it with `ncview` as I get the classic error

```
Note: could not open file /home/user/.ncviewrc for reading
Error: Can't open display:
```

I have tried what seems to be every guide to change this in my Windows 10 operating system. Let me take you through it:
First I check the `sshd_config` to check the `X11 forwarding`. Here, the error message is:

```
sshd_config: command not found
```

Then I learned, I could enable the `X11 forwarding` through PuTTY when I also had a X launch program (for me `Xming`). I tried to enable the `X11 forwarding` through the SSH part in PuTTY with my IP address. But, once it tries to connect to the host (same computer) I get a `PuTTY fatal error: Network error: Connection refused`. So I thought, do I even have a SSH connection, I checked that on https://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php. Here, I got another error telling me, I cannot connect with my SSH server. I think it is crucial to have a connection with the SSH, to enable `X11 forwarding` to then enable displaying in Ubuntu. But, for now, I am met with error upon error.

I have also tried with the `export DISPLAY=:0` and `$ ssh username@hostname -X` with little luck as well.

My question is simply, how do I fix all of this so I can use `ncview` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tested it with a simple X client such as `xeyes`? Ex. `ssh username@hostname -X` then type `xeyes`. Don't mess with the `DISPLAY` variable in the first instance, let PuTTY / SSH decide that for you. Make sure that `Xming` is actually running on the local Windows system.

Comment: Doing so, I get a similar error `Can't open display: `. I am pretty sure the `Xming` is running on the local Windows system. It seems really strange. Does it change anything that I am still working in the 18.04 version @steeldriver?

Comment: Wait a minute - are you doing ssh -X using PuTTY (either using `pssh` or by configuring the connection SSH -> X11 -> Enable X11 Forwarding? Or are you using WSL? If you have Xming + PuTTY I would avoid WSL altogether.

Comment: I think I have tried all possibilities. But, regarding your previous, I only did things in WSL, sorry. Nothing in PuTTY!

Comment: @steeldriver, I now understand the difference between using PuTTY and WSL. Nevertheless, I have tried with both, but I want to do it in WSL and be free of `xming` and PuTTY. Is it possible to resolve then?

Comment: sshd_config is a file, not a program. In order to check it you have to use an editor: 

`nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Also, do `xhost +localhost` BEFORE connecting via SSH (shouldn't necessary though). The remote SSH server may also be disallowing X11 forwarding.